# Assign sed command correctly

Tags: bash, sed, macos, escape-characters

I am trying to assign the result of a sed command to a variable in bash, but I am unable to escape everything corrrectly (probably just due to my lack of knowledge in bash), I have tried:

```
hash_in_podfile=$( sed -rn 's/^ *pod [\'\"]XXX["\'],.*:commit *=> *["\']([^\'"]*)["\'].*$/\1/p' ${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile )
```

but I am getting

> bash_playground.sh: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
> `''

**UPDATED SCRIPT**

This is the script I am using updated with the code from the answer. Only the path and the comment have changed:

```
#!\bin\sh
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH='/Users/path/to/file'

# just a comment
hash_in_podfile=$(sed -rnf - <<\! -- "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile"
s/^ *pod ['"]XXX["'],.*:commit *=> *["']([^'"]*)["'].*$/\1/p
!
)
echo $hash_in_podfile
```

executed with `sh script_name.sh`

`sh --version` yields:

> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
> Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

On execution I get:

```
script_name.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
script_name.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Can you add the data you are trying to match and the expected output?

Comment: the matching already works, when I execute the content of `$()` directly in the console I get a hexadecimal hash. The input is a file that contains a line that looks like this : `pod 'XXX', :git => 'git@github.YYY.net:ZZZ/AAA.git', :commit => '23401689216a1905bc137df'`. The output in this case would be `23401689216a1905bc137df`

Comment: You can try this `sed -E 's/^pod.*>..(.*)./\1/'` for the match.

Comment: @HatLess that does not seem to return the hash (it returns the whole file)

Comment: You can't use a single quote inside a single-quoted string. You don't need to escape double quotes inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: I have just tried it in 5 different labs and it works each time with different `sed` versions as too does `awk '{print $8}' inputfile | tr -d \'` to output `23401689216a1905bc137df`.  You can also change the `-E` to `-r`

Comment: The error mentions line 9.  This means that there are further lines in your script. Please show these in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues in your script:

1. The `sh` on macOS is a very old version of the `bash` shell, and it has a bug that stops you from using unbalanced quotes in here-documents in command substitutions:

   ```
   $ a=$( cat <<'END'
   > "
   > END
   > )
   > sh: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
   ```

   (I had to press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> after the `)` at the end there.)

   You can get by this by installing a newer `bash` shell from the Homebrew package manager (or equivalent), or by using the `zsh` shell on macOS.
2. The `sed` on macOS does not have an `-r` option.  To use extended regular expressions with `sed` on macOS, use `-E` (this is also supported by GNU `sed` nowadays).  Your expression does not use extended regular expression features though, so just removing the option would be ok too. macOS `sed` also can't use `-` as the option-argument to `-f` to mean "read from standard input".   Use `/dev/stdin` instead.

Suggestion:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH='/Users/path/to/file'

# just a comment

hash_in_podfile=$(sed -n -f /dev/stdin -- $PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH/Podfile <<'END'
s/^ *pod ['"]XXX["'],.*:commit *=> *["']([^'"]*)["'].*$/\1/p
END
)

echo $hash_in_podfile
```

If all you want to do is to output the value, then don't use an intermediate variable:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH='/Users/path/to/file'

# just a comment

sed -n -f /dev/stdin -- $PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH/Podfile <<'END'
s/^ *pod ['"]XXX["'],.*:commit *=> *["']([^'"]*)["'].*$/\1/p
END
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `heredoc` approach doesn't work for your system, then you can go fir an alternative of providing sed commands via shell variables:

```
hash_in_podfile=$(q=\"\'; sed -ne "s/^ *pod [$q]XXX[$q],.*:commit *=> *[$q]([^$q]*)[$q].*\$/\\1/p" -- "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile")
```

Although there are many ways you could do this, but the simplest is to supply the sed commands on the stdin via a quoted heredoc so that there is no need to escape sed characters which are meaningful for the shell.

```
hash_in_podfile=$(sed -rnf - <<\! -- "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile"
s/^ *pod ['"]XXX["'],.*:commit *=> *["']([^'"]*)["'].*$/\1/p
!
)
```

Comment: I get: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: In my test script I only have:

Comment: @Daniel You won't get that error if you use the command in the answer.

Comment: In my test script I only have: `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH='~/path/to/file'` + yourcode + `echo $hash_in_podfile` (on different lines), and I execute it with `sh testscript.sh`. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Im on OSX, in case that could be breaking things...

Comment: The `~` will not expand to the path of your home directory if it's quoted. This should give you a "file not found" or "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: I have tried using the full path, same result

Comment: I have updated the question with the full script

Comment: @Daniel provided an alternative, you nay try it out.

Comment: It did not work either, I ended up exchanging all `["']`with dot and `[^'"]` with `[0-9a-f]`

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
hash_in_podfile="$( sed -rn 's/^ *pod ['\''"]XXX["'\''],.*:commit *=> *["'\'']([^'\''"]*)["'\''].*$/\1/p' "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile" )"
```

The basic “trick” is in the way single-quotes are “escaped” within single-quotes: `echo 'before'\''after'` yields `before'after`. Given the way Bash expansion works, this will form a single token, as expected. An equivalent option would be `echo 'before'"'"'after'`, but the former syntax is slightly shorter.

To check whether the expanded command looks right, just print it out:

```bsh
echo sed -rn 's/^ *pod ['\''"]XXX["'\''],.*:commit *=> *["'\'']([^'\''"]*)["'\''].*$/\1/p' "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile"
```

BTW, it is good practice to use up-to-date software (e.g. version 5.1.8 in case of Bash) instead of badly outdated versions. In some cases a huge version discrepancy can make problems hard to reproduce and advice hard to follow.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: It depends. If you're writing for macOS, you may want to remain _portable_ by writing your scripts in such a way that the _default version of `bash` on the system_ is able to execute the code.  Doing that ensures that the shell code will be valid on any current macOS system. Release 3.2.57 of `bash` is very old, but it's going to remain the default version of that shell on macOS for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Admittedly, I had no clue about this limitation of macOS and generally didn’t consider flawed software environments in that paragraph. I prefer environments with rolling updates where individual components (such as Bash) have individual versions (up-to-date rather than frozen) and are updated independently. So my assumption was that even if a system gets installed with old Bash, it will eventually update the package. The fact that an old version needs to be kept forever is quite surprising to me.

Comment: In this particular case, it comes down to licensing issues.